# Error variable lengths differ ggsurvplot_facet

Tags: r, error-handling, survival-analysis, survival, survminer

I am trying to run `ggsurvplot_facet()`  but cannot get past `Error in model.frame.default(formula = surv_object2 ~ id, data = list( :variable lengths differ (found for 'id')`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I believe the error is in the `survfit()`/`surv_fit()` component and not in the `ggsurvplot_facet()` component.

The data can be found [here](https://universityofadelaide.box.com/s/7b9jhukacpz2pr3ju9icg7mlsc91i8q1).

My code is as follows:

```
library(survival); library(survminer)

read.csv(file = 'test.csv', header = TRUE)

surv_object <- Surv(time = test$Days_survived, event = test$Event1) 
fit <- survfit(surv_object ~ id, data = test)
ggsurvplot_facet(fit = fit, data = test, facet.by = "method", pval = TRUE)

# I have also tried, without success
fit <- survfit(Surv(join$Days_survived, join$Event1) ~ id, data = join) 
ggsurvplot_facet(fit = fit, data = test, facet.by = "method", pval = TRUE)

# and
fit <- survfit(as.formula(paste("Surv(join$Days_survived, join$Event1) ~", id)), data = join)
ggsurvplot_facet(fit = fit, data = test, facet.by = "method", pval = TRUE)

# and
fit <- survfit(as.formula(paste('Surv(join$Days_survived, join$Event1) ~', id)), data = join)
ggsurvplot_facet(fit = fit, data = test, facet.by = "method", pval = TRUE)

# and
fit <- survfit(as.formula(Surv(join$Days_survived, join$Event1) ~ id), data=join)
ggsurvplot_facet(fit = fit, data = test, facet.by = "method", pval = TRUE)
```

I have also tried all the above combinations using the `surv_fit()` function.

I have found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058769/how-to-fix-error-variable-lengths-differ-found-for-inputs-in-r-shiny) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772703/problems-with-calling-variables-in-r-survival-package), but I have not been able to solve my problem.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
lapply(c("survival", "survminer"), require, character.only=TRUE)
df <- read.csv(file = 'test.csv', header = TRUE)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time = Days_survived, event = Event1) ~ id, data=df)
ggsurvplot_facet(fit, facet.by = "method", pval = TRUE, data = df)
```

Result:
[image]