# ggsurvplot_facet p-values - error variable lengths differ

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival, survminer

I am trying to create a faceted survival plot with confidence intervals and p-values. The plot should look essentially equivalent to the below but with p-values.

[image]

However, I keep running into the error `variable lengths differ`.

I have found several posts with similar problems ([Post_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977238/error-variable-lengths-differ-ggsurvplot-facet), [Post_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54058769/how-to-fix-error-variable-lengths-differ-found-for-inputs-in-r-shiny), [Post_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38772703/problems-with-calling-variables-in-r-survival-package)), but none of these have yet helped me to solve my issue. I have also tried sub-setting my data in various ways so that all included variables were evenly balanced, but this didn't help either.

Any advice appreciated.

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggsurvfit)

# Read in data
dat <- structure(list(Rabbit = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 26L, 34L, 35L, 28L, 29L, 32L, 36L, 30L, 31L, 
33L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L), Treatment = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L), levels = c("Meat bait", 
"Soil spray", "Carrot bait", "Oat bait", "Control"), class = "factor"), 
    Survival.Time.Rabbit = c(68.5, 75, 51, 51, 99, 120, 240, 
    219, 336, 53, 29, 77, 77, 96, 149, 91.5, 77, 336, 336, 336, 
    77.67, 92.67, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 53.5, 73, 
    336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336, 336), Status.Rabbit = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Timepoint = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("1 Day post deployment", 
    "5 Days post deployment", "10 Days post deployment", "20 Days post deployment", 
    "40 Days post deployment", "60 Days post deployment"), class = "factor"), 
    Survival.Time.Bait1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 0L, NA, NA, 10L, 10L, NA, 
    NA, NA, 10L, 0L, NA, NA, 20L, 20L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 
    NA, 0L, NA, NA, 0L), Survival.Time.Bait2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, 
    10L, 10L, NA, NA, 10L, 10L, 10L, NA, 10L, 20L, 20L, NA, NA, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 60L, 60L, 60L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-42L), class = "data.frame")

# Define factors
dat$Timepoint <- factor(dat$Timepoint, levels = c("1 Day post deployment",
                                                  "5 Days post deployment",
                                                  "10 Days post deployment",
                                                  "20 Days post deployment",
                                                  "40 Days post deployment",
                                                  "60 Days post deployment"))

dat$Treatment <- factor(dat$Treatment, levels = c("Meat bait",
                                                  "Soil spray",
                                                  "Carrot bait",
                                                  "Oat bait",
                                                  "Control"))

# Create survival objects
surv <- Surv(time = dat$Survival.Time.Rabbit, event = dat$Status.Rabbit)

survfit.treatment.timepoint.rabbit <- survfit2(surv ~ Treatment, conf.int = T, data = dat)

# Plot
ggsurvplot_facet(survfit.treatment.timepoint.rabbit, 
                         facet.by = "Timepoint", size = 1.5, 
                         data = dat, conf.int = T, font.x = c(12, face = "bold"),
                         font.y = c(12, face = "bold"), font.tickslab = c(10), pval = T) + 
  labs(x = "Time to death (hours)",
       y = "Survival probability")

# Note code for plot above runs fine in absence of pval = T
```